# The operation 'uploadBytesResumable' cannot be performed on a root reference, create a non-root reference using child

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I was using Firebase services without rules for testing like this:
`allow read, write: if true;` and when I decide to set rules this problem happened suddenly!

`allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`

> FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: The operation 'uploadBytesResumable' cannot be performed on a root reference, create a non-root reference using child, such as .child('file.png'). (storage/invalid-root-operation)

Before changing the rules, I uploaded many images to storage and view them in my app, but now I'm trying with all my information without any changes!!

This is the method which I use to upload the images, I didn't change anything in it before or after changing the rules:

```
Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

  Future uploadImage() async {
    reference.child('Items/${itemNameController.text}.jpg');
    await reference.putData(
      webImage!,
      SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'),
    );
    downloadUrl = await reference.getDownloadURL();
    update();
  }
```

By the way, I'm using Flutter web.

And I'm using this package: `firebase_storage: ^11.0.6`

### Update

I will put here the full code for my operation, the problem is happening when I try to upload to fireStorage, but there is another function to store data in fireStore.

I have tried the solution that typed down by Someone, but still have the same problem when I combine functions (FireStorage - FireStore) with each other:

```
 Database database = Database();
  String? id;

  Future saveToDb() async {
    var formData = formKey.currentState;
    if (formData!.validate()) {
      await uploadImage().whenComplete(() async {
        await addToFireStore();
        clearData();
        Get.snackbar(
          'Adding done',
          'Adding item done successfully',
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
          borderRadius: Dimensions.radius20,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
            Dimensions.width30,
            Dimensions.height20,
            Dimensions.width40,
            Dimensions.height20,
          ),
        );
        update();
      });
    }
  }

  Future uploadImage() async {
    await database.reference.child('Items/${itemNameController.text}.jpg').putData(
          webImage!,
          SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'),
        );
    downloadUrl = await database.reference.getDownloadURL();
    update();
  }

  Future addToFireStore() async {
    for (var i in database.categoriesModel) {
      if (database.categoryValue == i.name) {
        id = i.id;
      }
    }
    await database.catCollectionRef
        .doc(id)
        .collection('Items')
        .doc(const Uuid().v4())
        .set({
      'id': const Uuid().v4(),
      'Name': itemNameController.text,
      'Decryption': itemDescController.text,
      'Availability': switchValue.toString(),
      'Category': database.categoryValue,
      'Quantity type': quantityValue,
      'Quantity value': itemQuanController.text,
      'Price': itemPriceController.text,
      'Image': downloadUrl,
    });
    update();
  }

  clearData() {
    webImage?.clear();
    itemNameController.clear();
    itemDescController.clear();
    itemQuanController.clear();
    itemPriceController.clear();
    database.categoryValue = 'Choose one';
    switchValue = false;
    quantityValue = 'Choose One';
    downloadUrl = '';
    update();
  }
```

I use the `saveToDb()` function in the UI button to set the whole operation, but returns the same problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

you're referencing to the root directlt, calling the `child()` on statement will not change the reference, try:

```
   Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

  Future uploadImage() async {
    
    await reference.child('Items/${itemNameController.text}.jpg').putData(
      webImage!,
      SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'),
    );
    downloadUrl = await reference.getDownloadURL();
    update();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you man, I've tried it and it works, but still there are little problems:
1- Before setting the rules it was working in this way (My code), now I have to edit it?!!
2- it doesn't store the url in the variable I've putted !!!
3- I typed new function to store data in FireStore, it works but without storing the image URL , even when I typed it in the same function of uploading image !!!

Comment: you need to make sure it's asynchronuos too, put a snippet

Comment: ofcourse I did, but nothing happened

Comment: can you incluse a snippet of code, and tell me where you expect it to happen but it did not ?

Comment: Please see the update of my post, I put it today, it has the full code operation